# React Native TouchableOpacity not working on children

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `TouchableOpacity` that does not execute the `onPress` event when I click on a child component inside of it. The onpress event is a simple console.log();

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1}} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>
    {this.state.customComponent}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If I click on an empty space inside of `TouchableOpacity` it will execute the `onPress`. If I click directly on the child component it will not execute.

Edit: I figured out the problem, it was because the `TouchableOpacity` had its child component render a `TouchableHighlight` unfortunately you you can't have a `TouchableHighlight` as a child

Comment: I recommend setting up an example at https://rnplay.org so that we can witness for ourselves and tweak the code in helpful ways.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same exact problem, I have other touchable opacities within my app and they work perfectly well except one.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem today. The solution was an easy fix: I imported the `TouchableOpacity` from `"react-native-gesture-handler"`, it should be imported from `"react-native"`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a few years late but I hope it helps someone. I had a similar issue and found that one of the parent views(Not immediate parent) was actually covering a large part of the Touchable opacity, I solved my issue by increasing the height of the above mentioned parent. It was difficult to find because its overflow was not hidden. Changing the parent elements overflow to hidden might help with finding out what's actually blocking the touchable opacity.